# Query String to redirect from page 1 to page 1 through Page 2( call buttonclick programmatically)

Tags: c#, asp.net

In Page 1, I have a link. When it is clicked, it should call the same page with different things, which i cannot do.

```
protected void lnkAddLoc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MerchantId = CommonHelper.GetLoggedInMerchant();
    string QueryStringValue2 = ApplicationData.URL_MERCHANT_PROFILE + 
        "?MerchantCompanyPayment";
    Response.Redirect(QueryStringValue2);
}
```

So it calls Page 2. Page 2 has a button through which i can go to Page 1. Button Code is here.

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    MerchantID = CommonHelper.GetLoggedInMerchant();

    string QueryString = ApplicationData.URL_MERCHANT_COMPANY_PAYMENT + 
        "?MerchantProfilePages";

    Response.Redirect(QueryString);
}
```

In the page load of Page 1, i want to call the button event handler.

```
if (string.Equals(QueryStringValue2, "MerchantCompanyPayment"))
{
    btnAdd._________________________
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you move the redirect code out of the event handler and call it from two places.  If I understand correctly, you want to automatically jump to page 2, process, then jump back to page 1.  Don't bother with the button click, just call the response.redirect directly.  I may be missing the point here, and if so you may want to clarify what you're asking...

Comment: Fantastic!! I missed the logic:( Thanks!!